# Optimizing query with large result set

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I have a CakePHP model, let's call it `Thing` which has an associated model called `ItemView`. `ItemView` represents one page view of the `Thing` item. I want to display how many times `Thing` has been viewed, so I do the following in my view:

```
<?php echo count($thing['ItemView']); ?>
```

This works, however as time goes on the result set of this query is going to get huge, as it's currently being returned like so:

```
array(
    'Thing' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'thing' => 'something'
    ),
    'ItemView' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'thing_id' => 1,
            'created' => '2013-09-21 19:25:39',
            'ip_address' => '127.0.0.1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'thing_id' => 1,
            'created' => '2013-09-21 19:25:41',
            'ip_address' => '127.0.0.1'
        ),
        // etc...
    )
)
```

How can I adapt the model `find()` to retrieve something like so:

```
array(
    'Thing' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'thing' => 'something',
        'views' => 2
    )
)
```

without loading the entire `ItemView` relation into memory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's pretty straight forward, we can make use of [`countercache`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count) - Cake does the counting for you whenever a record is added into/deleted from`ItemView`:

- Nothing to change in your `Thing.php` model
- Add a new `INT` column `views` in your `things` table.
- In your `ItemView.php` model, add `counterCache` like this:

  ```
  public $belongsTo = array(
      'Thing' => array(
          'counterCache' => 'views'
      )
  );
  ```

Then next time when you do addition/deletion via `ItemView`, Cake will automatically recalculate the counting and cache into `views` for you, so the next time when you do the query, you also need to make sure you specify `recursive = -1` as what [@Paco Car has suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18939440/534862):

```
$this->Thing->recursive = -1;
$this->Thing->find(...); //this will returns array of Thing + the field "views"

// --- OR ---

$this->Thing->find(array(
    'conditions' => array(
        //... your usual conditions here
    ),

    //... fields, order... etc

    //this will make sure the recursive applies to this call, once only.
    'recursive' => -1
);
```